# How to make it simply by using for in python

Tags: python, for-loop

This is a part of the my code.

DESCRIPTION :
 I read 8 csv files named from 11DD.csv to 18DD.csv. 
And using DATAFRAME, I named the column such as "Day", "Hour" and "TEM".
And then, I only need "TEM" column.
That's why i made this code like that way.

However, i think it could be much simply by using for sentence...
Help...

```
TEM1= pd.read_csv('DATA/11DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM2= pd.read_csv('DATA/12DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM3= pd.read_csv('DATA/13DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM4= pd.read_csv('DATA/14DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM5= pd.read_csv('DATA/15DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM6= pd.read_csv('DATA/16DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM7= pd.read_csv('DATA/17DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
TEM8= pd.read_csv('DATA/18DD.csv', names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])


T1= [TEM1['TEM']]
T2= [TEM2['TEM']]
T3= [TEM3['TEM']]
T4= [TEM4['TEM']]
T5= [TEM5['TEM']]
T6= [TEM6['TEM']]
T7= [TEM7['TEM']]
T8= [TEM8['TEM']]

X= [T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8]
sns.boxplot(data=X, linewidth =3, notch= False, palette="Blues", width= 0.2)
```

That's what i tried before

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
Year_data= []
for f in sorted(glob.glob(input_path)) :
     df = pd.read_csv(f, names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
     all_data = all_data([df])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using a for loop as following. Idea is to loop over the file numbers from 11 to 18 and use them for reading files within the for loop using `%str(t)` dynamically where `%s` will be replaced by 11, 12, 13, and so on thereby loading a different file each time.

```
for t in range(11, 19):
    TEM = pd.read_csv('DATA/%sDD.csv' %str(t), names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
    T = [TEM['TEM']]
    # Do processing with T
```

EDIT: To access T's outside the for loop, you can store them in some list and later loop over them for post-processing.

```
T_list = []
for t in range(11, 19):
    TEM = pd.read_csv('DATA/%sDD.csv' %str(t), names = ['Day','Hour','TEM'], skiprows=[0])
    T = [TEM['TEM']]
    T_list.append(T)


# Outside for loop (using your example code)

sns.boxplot(data=T_list, linewidth =3, notch= False, palette="Blues", width= 0.2)

# Or if you want to do something with T1, T2, T3 and so on individually

for T in T_list:
    # Do something with T
```

Comment: Thank you so much. another Question is How to use T1,T2,T3 outside of  for loop sentence

Comment: You can store them in some list and then later process outside by looping over them. I added in my answer